# ASP.NET Core with React

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I've been a react developer for many years. I'm learning how to integrate it with ASP.NET Core.  I created a new project using Visual Studio's ASP.NET Core with React.js template. My question is, how can I see a console.log in the browser? I've added it to the javascript code, but it doesn't appear in the browser's dev tools. Adding a breakpoint in the Javascript doesn't work either. So how can I verify values?

Comment: one of the benefits of using VS here would be the ability to add breakpoints to the javascript.  You should try and solve whatever issue is preventing that.  As a workaround for your current problem, you could use alert() for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Added the breakpoint in the code in VS was exactly what I needed.  I'm not used to that working.